# Kafka streams stopping threads on exception

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

In a kafka streams application if the process() method in your processor throws an uncaught exception the stream task will be killed.  However if you have a punctuate() method (using context.schedule()) and it throws an uncaught exception the task will not be killed.  Why is this?  What is the proper way to kill the task if you wanted uncaught exceptions in punctuate() to stop the task?

Comment: What version are use using? Throwing an exception should actually kill the task.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax 2.1.1.  just to confirm,  if punctuate throws an uncaught exception is should kill the task?

Comment: Yes, from my understanding (had a quick look into the code) it should kill the whole thread -- and afterwards, all task would be migrated to a different thread.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, my understanding when a task throws an uncaught exception that task is dead until you restart the application.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: That is not correct. When an exception is thrown, the corresponding thread dies and all its task will be migrated (via rebalancing) to the remaining threads. You would need to restart an application instance to recover dead threads though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification my misunderstanding.